# Updating id references into additional table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm having a little trouble (possibly codeblind currently) when it comes to migrating some data.

I have 2 tables, one is an appliance table, the other lists manufacturers. The original database stores all the data in a single table, which I'm splitting into multiple tables. I've managed to extract the manufacturers fine, as with the rest of the appliance details to the relevant tables. What I'm failing to do is link the id of the manufacturer to the appliance.

So what I want is for the id in the appliance table to be the corresponding id relative to the manufacturer name in the other table, but done in a single query from the original source material.

My original insert code as follows:

```
insert into c_appliance (app_serial, property_id, app_location,
                         app_installdate, app_warrantyexp, app_nextservice)
  select [Serial No#], [Customer Number], location,
         installed, [Expiry Date], [Service Due]
  from dbo.[Customer Table]
```

This doesn't add the manufacturer into the appliance table - which I'm aware of. The manufacturer column currently remains as null while i attempt to figure out what I'm missing.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: show us the original table definition, and how you defined the two new tables , including FK.

Comment: To get an answer you should start here. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: thanks for the advice sean, i will refer to that page in the future

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all create a unique key column in original table (temporarily) if not there.

Then insert in first table, as in the above query you are inserting in `c_appliance`. Also add the temporary unique key column.

Similarly insert into `Manufacturer` table in the same way, with temporary unique key column.

Now update you can set primary key and foreign keys on the basis of this unique key column.

Comment: I was being stupid with my original inserts. Too much time spent staring at the screen. Thanks for the swift kick